# How do you download the last file that was added in a directory on internet?

Tags: r

I would like to download the last archive (meteorological data) that has been added to this website by using Rstudio;

https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/hourly/radolan/recent/asc/

Do you know how to do it? I am able to download one in particular, but then I have to write the exact extension and It should be manually changed every time, and I do not want that, I want it automatically detected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's bit naïve (no error checking, blindly takes the last link from the file list page), but works with that particular listing.

Most of web scraping in R happens through *rvest* , `html_element("a:last-of-type")` extracts the last element of type `<a>` though CSS selector - your last archive. And `html_attr('href')` extracts the `href` attribute from that last `<a>`-element - actual link to the file.

```r
library(rvest)

last_link <- function(url) {
  last_href <- read_html(url) |> 
          html_element("a:last-of-type") |> 
          html_attr('href')
  paste0(url,last_href)
}

url <- "https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/hourly/radolan/recent/asc/"
last_link(url)
#> [1] "https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/hourly/radolan/recent/asc/RW-20220720.tar.gz"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The function `download_CDC()` downloads the files for you. Input number `1` will download the lastest one with their respective name provided by the website.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

base_url <- "https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/hourly/radolan/recent/asc/"

files <- base_url  %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_elements("a+ a") %>%  
  html_attr("href") 


download_CDC <- function(item_number) {
  base_url <- "https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/hourly/radolan/recent/asc/"
  download.file(paste0(base_url, files[item_number]), 
                destfile = files[item_number],
                mode = "wb")
  
}

download_CDC(1)
```